# é possivel apertar um botão em um form e ele pegar o $_POST do outro form?

Tags: php

tenho uma função que cadastra cliente

Se o usuario apertar no botão de cadastrar o cliente, vai executar a função

Se o usuario apertar no botao de cadastrar telefone, vai executar a mesma função e em seguida vai cadastrar o telefone desse cliente.

tenho o cadastro de cliente em um `<form>` e está passando por $_POST e o cadastro de telefone em outro `<form>` tambem por $_POST

quando aperto no cadastro de telefone, ele cadastra o cliente em seguida cadastra o telefone porém ele não passa os valores do primeiro form, então todos os campos do cliente ficam vazios e todos os campos de telefone preenchidos

Obs: se eu colocar um form dentro do outro, o botão de cadastro de cliente simplesmente não funciona

Comment: Por favor coloque os códigos aqui para facilitar nosso entendimento.

Comment: Provavelmente você só precisa de um FORM e cliente e telefone serem campos INPUT dentro desse único FORM,

Comment: Você não deve colocar um form dentro do outro, eles devem ficar em separado. Com os forms em separado, quando você utilizar o botão de submit, o objeto $_POST somente vai ter os campos daquele formulário que você clicou.

Comment: A cada POST enviado de um submit de formulário ao servidor o form é responsável apenas pela sua coleção de dados

Comment: alguma alternativa para esse problema? o que preciso é q um botão cadastre o cliente, o outro botão vai servir para cadastrar telefone, porém se o usuario não  apertou no botão de cadastrar o cliente, o mesmo irá cadastrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque todos os campos que deseja cadastrar dentro do mesmo formulário:

Exemplo:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="POST">
  Cliente:<br>
  <input type="text" name="cliente">
  <br>
  Telefone:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 



<?php
$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
?>
```

Comment: Você me deu uma ideia melhor, como estou fazendo o cadastro de telefone em uma modal, coloco um if para dizer q se eu estiver cadastrando o cliente o modal fica dentro do form de cadastro de cliente e se não estiver vão se tornar dois forms separados, muito obrigado

Comment: Entendi, por nada !